# Can't increase jumbotron width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am newbie to web development. Issue that I am encountering in my jumbo-tron is that it is not increasing its width in my phone and my text is overflowing from it. I want to adjust that so that jumbotron fits the "People-Things line". Here is the problem image: 
Here is my Html http://pastebin.com/CgNSPLeE .

[image]

**Current code:**

```css
@media (min-width: 414px) and (max-width: 736 px) {
  #main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

  }
  #people-things a {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50px;
    left: 150px;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Always create a fiddle of your problem. For your case, I've made it here: https://jsfiddle.net/xVB3t/
You havent included all of relevant CSS. Please do so.

Comment: Try doing #people-things { font-size: 50%; } or some percentage what suits. Giving the font size in percentage make the font scale according to the browser size.

Comment: You are targeting #main .container, but there is no .container DIV inside your #main DIV as up to your HTML

Comment: @markoffden i had edited still the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

it seems you're trying to place things in your way. Bootstrap is a CSS framework that does things in complete way, so you don't need to add any position-CSS code. Because that's managed by Bootstrap CSS. 
You don't need to place that CSS. 
If what you want is to place the text "People-Things Recomentations" inside the jumbotron, it's enough placing an **h1** or **h3** inside it. To achieve the perfect Bootstrap sync, it's better use of h1, then if you want it smaller, you can use CSS to change its size.
Bootstrap's grid system works in 12 columns, but in case of jumbotron, they work in another way. This is the html you'll need:

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="main">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <h1><a href="#">People-Things Recomendation</a></h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

To change colors of items and so on, you can use CSS in this way: 
For example you want to change color of "People-Things Recomendation":

```
div#main h1 {
 color: blue;
}
```

I hope this is what you meant; if it isn't, let me know.
Cheers!

Comment: it doesn't matter,issue is still persisting.

Comment: Are you including any other CSS files inside your <head> tags?
Because this should be the simplest way. It's like how [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron) says.
Could you paste your full HTML?

Comment: Here is my rest css code  #main {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 90px;
    width: auto;
}

Comment: So... just try removing all of this CSS code. If you want a title **inside** the Jumbotron, you don't need any CSS.
You just need the html I published, because Bootstrap will handle everything!
Try removing your CSS.

Comment: Nops Man its still not fixing but its becoming fuzzy on smaller devices when i use your proposed solution

Comment: Could you paste all your HTML code inside [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)?
Because it's really strange.
If you remove all your CSS and you use **just** the HTML I provided you, that's really strange.
So if you can, please paste your HTML and link it, so I can check.
Or at least, paste from **<!DOCTYPE html>** to the end of the jumbotron div. (including the head).
Bootstrap handles everything in the right way even on small devices, because it's built mobile-first.
Or at least, try using [Bootstrap's Getting Started template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template).

Comment: Okay, perfect. I'm going to correct it. Evermore, could you paste in pastebin the content of Saver_temp.min.css?
Anyway your code is confused; because you should indent everything how should be. Instead, there are long divs that open and close in the same line!
I'm fixing everything for you, but please paste that CSS source so I can have the same style you want.

Comment: Okay, you don't need to provide me that CSS file.
I did it, but of course text in mobile-layout will not be in a single line, because it's too large. If you want that it is on a single line, just use CSS with min-width and max-width with **font-size: Npx/em**. This is the [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/rZJNdS2p), tell me if it's okay. I have closed body and html too; you hadn't.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much man. Yeah i know my indentation sucks. I am a new learner. Sorry. Wait give me a moment i am checking it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.jumbotron` should have inside a `.container` and a grid div `.col-md-12` and then it'll adapt to its parent container.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h3 id="people-things"><a href="#">PEOPLE-THINGS RECOMENDATION</a></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5"> <!--empty--> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8"> <!--empty--> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then play with bootstrap's [responsive classes/utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) so you have the desired effect.

*it's an anti-pattern to use bootstrap and to force the layout with more properties. If using bootstrap, try to achieve what you want with the default classes.

Comment: @juanmni here is my html can you fix this?

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSiddiqui you should target font-size on media queries.
something like [this](http://jsbin.com/fuwame/edit?html,css,output)